# Failed to implement Nginx caching - connection refused

Tags: 16.04, server, php, nginx, cache

I'm having trouble getting my site to work after trying to implement Nginx caching.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial), Nginx (1.10.3), PHP-FPM (7.0) and WordPress.

Port 9000 (for php-fpm) is unfiltered by UFW.

### Reproducing my environment

#### 1 - setting confs:

- [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/bendqh/ac03e117f1256f3c70b0d088daa86fbf)
- [default conf](https://gist.github.com/bendqh/e9e981f781ece9d231b0a89722964048)
- [virtual host](https://gist.github.com/bendqh/5d588bccfa499a016f2554dc1b71eb67)
- [/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf](https://gist.github.com/bendqh/43880d2f2b403743e6725b887c765e91) (comments omitted)

#### 2 - Creating a cache dir:

```
mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/cache/
chmod 755 /var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/cache/
chown www-data:www-data /var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp/cache/
```

#### 3 - Server restart:

```
systemctl restart nginx.service
/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart
```

#### 4- Error and debug tries:

```
*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,
client: MY_IP_ADDRESS, server: example.com, request: "GET /
HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000".
```

**The browser gives:**

```
502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

**Debug:**

```
/etc/init.d/php*-fpm status
```

brings:

```
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-04-27 07:09:28 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 16336 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/php/php7.0-fpm-checkconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16346 (php-fpm7.0)
   Status: "Ready to handle connections"
```

### My question

Why is the connection refused and my site is down?

### Update for NerdOfLinux:

```
+ curl -I example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
```

And

```
grep "listen" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep -v ";"
+ grep --color=auto -v ';'
+ grep --color=auto listen /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

Comment: Can we get the output of `curl -I`?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux question edited.

Comment: Can we get the `fastcgi_pass` directive in your virtual host, and the output of `sudo fuser 9000/tcp` along with `sudo grep "listen" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | grep -v ";"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue at play is a misconfiguration by you of the nginx `fastcgi_pass` directive to point at a nonexistent backend/upstream gateway.

Since 14.10 (or was it 15.10, I dont remember now exactly) `php-fpm` listens on a local UNIX socket and not TCP port 9000 by default.  I know this because I spearheaded the effort to make this change in Ubuntu and Debian for the defaults for FPM, and it was accepted in the packaging.  And I know this is your setup because of the `listen =` line of your FPM `www.conf` which says its listening on a socket.

Put `unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` in your `fastcgi_pass` directive in the `nginx` server block, and not the `127.0.0.1:9000` you have.  That should then allow it to work properly because the correct PHP upstream gateway is then used.

Answer (score -1):

check in your php-fpm pool definition which is to be found in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d`

User www-data is used to run php-fpm:

`user = www-data
 group = www-data`

Comment: That's exactly my definition there.

Comment: Core issue is that OP didnt pay attention to FPM's `listen` line and therefore has NGINX handing off to the wrong location. I see this error all the time its why the *actual* default package configs (the sample in `sites-available/default` from the package on a clean install of NGINX) have both the `php-cgi` and `php-fpm` `fastcgi_pass` options in the default example config with the FPM one uncommented by default.